# Epiphany browser does not autostart

Tags: raspbian, lxde

On my Pi, `cat /etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE/autostart` gives the following:

```
@lxpanel --profile LXDE
@pcmanfm --desktop --profile LXDE
@epiphany-browser http://localhost/ticker/start.py
```

The graphical desktop launches, but the epiphany-browser does not start. How do I troubleshoot or where are all the places which can control what is launched automatically?

Answer (score 0):

The location of the autostart file has moved.  It is now in `/etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE-pi`.

Previously, it was working fine.  Then I upgraded the distribution, and things stopped working.

This question should be moved back to the Raspberry Pi site.